# Horizontal Recyclerview not scrolling inside FramLayout or CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/carousal_parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </FrameLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in Inner `FrameLayout` i am adding a Horizontal `Recyclerview` with fixed Size .

```
carousel_parent_layout = findViewById(R.id.carousal_parent_layout);
 carouselPager = view.findViewById(R.id.carouselPager);
    carouselPagerAdapter = new CarouselPagerAdapter(mContext, carouselData, carouselPager);
    carouselPager.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    carouselPager.setHasFixedSize(true);

carousel_parent_layout.addView(carouselPager);
```

But on touching `Recyclerview` it is not flinging . I have tried with SnapHelper and  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but nothing is working. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance for reading the question.

Comment: I think your items do not have a width. Try to set some size manually just for the sake of testing. It might be that items are just size 0.

Comment: Might be a problem, they way you create `carouselPager`. Where do you create it? 
And what is the size of it? 
Might be so, that `carouselPager` is not added to the layout (if it's null) or it's an incorrect size.

Comment: @IoaneSharvadze  First item is displaying properly and i have tried setting height and width for testing purpose but items in screen width only are getting displayed . Scrolling and flinging is not working :(

Comment: There might be similar problem if you have `RecyclerView` inside `Scrollview`.